# Using Tinker with OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I am new to Laravel and OctoberCMS,

i would like to run tinker, so I navigate to my root directory where my OctoberCMS Instance is and the artisan file is located

I then enter in the Terminal the following command:

```
php artisan tinker
```

and i get the following error:

**[ErrorException]
  The use statement with non-compound name 'BackendAuth' has no effect**

Any suggestions to resolve this or tell me what I am doing wrong would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I had a reference where the namespace was not explicit into my routes.php file of a custom plugin.

```
use BackendAuth;
```

when I made the reference explicit I was able to get Artisan to work without issue.

```
use Backend\Facades\BackendAuth;
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you try to use tinker on clear installation?

In my october,  tinker work great.

Comment: not sure why someone down voted you, however your statement was helpful as I was able to isolated the problem to my code.